# Clicking on menu item in Chrome does nothing

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, cross-browser

Evening all,

I am struggling with a couple of problems that I could do with your help with.  I apologise if these have been covered in other pages, if they have could you point me in the direction of those pages.  The problems are as follows:

1. I've got a simple website that contains a master page with a menu on it.  The menu works fine with IE and Firefox but when I try it in Chrome clicking the menu doesn't seem to work.

Here is how I have set the menu up:

How do I get the click on the menu to display the correct page?

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Height="16px" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                style="margin-top: 0px" Width="917px">
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Images/MenuHome.jpg" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" 
                       ></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Images/MenuMenu.jpg" NavigateUrl="~/Menu.aspx" 
                        ></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Images/MenuPriceList.jpg" NavigateUrl="~/PriceList.aspx" 
                        ></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Images/MenuOrdering2.jpg" 
                        NavigateUrl="~/Ordering.aspx" >
                    </asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Images/MenuOccasions.jpg" 
                        NavigateUrl="~/Occasions.aspx">
                    </asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Images/MenuWeddings2.jpg" NavigateUrl="~/Weddings.aspx" 
                        ></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Images/MenuEvents.jpg" NavigateUrl="~/Events.aspx" 
                        ></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Images/MenuGallery.jpg" NavigateUrl="~/Gallery.aspx" 
                        ></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Images/MenuContactUs.jpg" 
                        NavigateUrl="~/ContactUs.aspx" >
                    </asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Images/MenuBlog.jpg" 
                        NavigateUrl="~/dasblog/default.aspx" >
                    </asp:MenuItem>
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
```

1. The menu is wrapping round on to two rows, how do I keep it on a single row?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging I have found the solution.
The answer can be found here: http://forums.asp.net/p/1369765/2860698.aspx#2860698

I've copied the bits you will need and pasted it in here:

You need to add an App_Browsers folder to the project and add a new item Add New Item...
Select "Browser File" and name it Chrome.browsers.
Comment out the default stuff and insert this from the link above:

```
<browsers>
    <browser refID="safari1plus">
        <controlAdapters>
            <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu" adapterType="" />
        </controlAdapters>
    </browser>
</browsers>
```

This will make the menu work, and it also stops it from wrapping around.